# how to get clean error msg in `nest js` when we are using nested array of objects

Tags: nestjs, nested-loops, class-validator

I am looking for a solution where we can show error msg in below format

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "name should not be empty",
    "timestamp": "2023-05-17T09:29:49.646Z"
}
```

than this

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "featureData.0.data.net.0.name should not be empty",
    "timestamp": "2023-05-17T09:38:49.010Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I surfed in google and didn't found a proper solution. So, creating my own solution based on bits and pieces:

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response, } from 'express';
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http';

export const getStatusCode = (exception: any): number => {
  return exception instanceof HttpException
    ? exception.getStatus()
    : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
};

export const getErrorMessage = (exception: any): string => {
  if (typeof(exception) === 'object') {
    return exception[0];
  }
  return exception;
};

@Catch(HttpException)
export class GlobalExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
        const request = ctx.getRequest<IncomingMessage>();
        const code = getStatusCode(exception);
        const message = getErrorMessage(exception.response.message);
        const statusCode = exception.getStatus();

        const messageSplit = message.split('.').pop();

        response.status(code).json({
          statusCode,
          message: messageSplit,
          timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        });
    }
};
```

This solution worked as expected after splitting the message based on `.` and sending last index element in `Array`.